# Can graves be removed to make way for urban development?

Tags: sharia, grave

Suppose there is a Muslim graveyard whose land now needs to be reused for urban development (e.g. building houses, apartments, malls, etc.). My questions are:

- Is this legal in Islam?
- Can buildings be built over the graves, or must the human remains be exhumed first?
- If exhumed, what is the proper way to deal with the remains?

Comment: Was the Muslim graveyard a waqf property? If so it can not be bought or sold, and hence can not be obtained by anyone to use for purposes you have mentioned.

Comment: @UmH I am assuming that this graveyard is located in a jurisdiction where the government has the power to take private property i.e. [eminent domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eminent_domain), compulsory purchase, or expropriation.